# Insert the last element in the middle of array in c++?

Tags: c++

the code changes the place of other elements, I want output was without changing
if size = 6  elements 1 2 3 4 5 0 the output should be 1 2 3 0 5 6 but the code outputs 1 3 5 0 2 4

below my coding implementation in c++ I want to where exactly I am making mistake

the code changes the place of other elements, I want output was without changing
if size = 6  elements 1 2 3 4 5 0 the output should be 1 2 3 0 5 6 but the code outputs 1 3 5 0 2 4

below my coding implementation in c++ I want to where exactly I am making mistake

```
  #include <iostream> 
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node 
{
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
};

class LinkedList 
{
private:
    struct Node* head, * mid;
    int count;

public:
    LinkedList();
    void insertAtMiddle(int);
    void show();
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    mid = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

// Функция для вставки node в
// середина связанного списка
void LinkedList::insertAtMiddle(int n)
{
    struct Node* temp = new struct Node();
    struct Node* temp1;

    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->value = n;

    // Если количество элементов меньше 2
    if (count < 1) 
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp1 = head;
            temp1->next = temp;
        }
        count++;
        // mid points to first element 
        mid = head;
    }

    // If the number of elements already present 
    // are greater than 2 
    else
    {

        temp->next = mid->next;
        mid->next = temp;
        count++;

        // If number of e lements after insertion 
        // are odd 
        if (count %  2!= 0) 
        {

            // mid points to the newly 
            // inserted node

            mid = mid->next;
        }
    }
}


// Function to print the nodes 
// of the linked list 
void LinkedList::show()
{
    struct Node* temp;
    temp = head;
    // Initializing temp to head 
    // Iterating and printing till 
    // The end of linked list 
    // That is, till temp is null 
    while (temp != NULL) 
    {
        cout << temp->value << " -> ";
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    cout << "NULL";
    cout << endl;
}

// Driver code 
int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int a;
    a= sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    LinkedList L1;
    cout << "Enter the size of the array\n";

    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter the values\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "The values entered are\n";
   
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    L1.insertAtMiddle(arr[i]);
    L1.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: yes but could not where the function changes the place

Comment: Use pen and paper to draw the operations you perform on the list. Draw boxes for the nodes, and arrows for the links. As you step through the code in the debugger, draw them down on paper. Erase and redraw arrows as you modify pointers.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)?

Comment: @Eljay No, can you add it and send me?

Comment: When you do the *insert last element from end to middle* operation from `1 2 3 4 5 0` so the output should be `1 2 3 0 5 6`, where does the `6` come from?  Where did the `4` disappear?  Why isn't the output supposed to be `1 2 3 0 4 5`?

Comment: @Eljay Sorry it is my mistake), yes it should be 4, I want the output was 1 2 3 0 4 5 , not like this 1 3 5 0 2 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::rotate` to move the end element to the middle.

For the problem you posed:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using std::advance;
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::rotate;
using std::vector;

static ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, vector<int> const& v) {
    char const* sep = "";
    for (auto i : v) {
        out << sep << i;
        sep = " ";
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    using diff_t = vector<int>::iterator::difference_type;
    auto v = vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
    auto sz = static_cast<diff_t>(v.size());
    auto pos = static_cast<diff_t>(v.size() / 2);
    auto f = v.begin();
    advance(f, pos);
    auto fn = v.begin();
    advance(fn, sz-1);
    auto e = v.end();
    rotate(f, fn, e);
    cout << v << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother, can you make your code for N numbers?

Comment: The code will handle moving the last element to the middle of a vector of size 3 or larger.